# Or operand with int in if statement

Tags: java, eclipse, int, operand

My problem is that program is not reading codes as i intended "he" would.

I have

```
if (hero.getPos() == (6 | 11 | 16)) {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Right", "Left"};
} else {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Down", "Right", "Left"};
}
```

When hero position is 6, the program still goes to else.

Why is that? Is it because of operands? If yes, how should i change it?

Comment: Python: if a in (1,2,5): ...
If these are constants that you know of, then you can maybe do some bit trickery. If the list of numbers is large, then throw them into a set, and check if ci.getNumber() is also in that set.

Comment: what would you like to do after you compare the values?

Comment: You have to do individual `==` for each value under test.

Comment: So no easy way around doing like i did?

Comment: A possible `switch` statement

Comment: then cases are repeating (6, 11, 16)

Comment: Just don't add a break -> `case 6: case 11: case 16: dosmt(); break;`

Comment: Ah yes, thats a possibility :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
if (hero.getPos() == 6 || hero.getPos() == 11 || hero.getPos() == 16)) {
```

This will do what you want.

What you did is comparing `hero.getPos()` with the result of `(6|11|16)` which will do [bitwise or](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) between those numbers.

Comment: I was in the middle of adding it :)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct, just thinking differently you may use Sets.

```
static final Set<Integer> positions = new HashSet<Integer>();
static{
    positions.add(6);
    positions.add(11);
    positions.add(16);
}

if (positions.contains(hero.getPos())){
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Right", "Left"};
} else {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Down", "Right", "Left"};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it like that. It ors the 3 number bitwise.

You have to do like this :

```
if (hero.getPos() == 6 || hero.getPos() == 11 | hero.getPos() == 16)) {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Right", "Left"};
} else {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Down", "Right", "Left"};
}
```

You see the difference ? `|` is a bitwise or while `||` is a logical or.
Note also that you have to rewrite the comparison each time.

Answer (score 2):

`(6 | 11 | 16)` would be evaluated first to 31 (binary operation), which is `6 != 31`. Not what you want.

Better is to check every single position (you have only 3, so inline is good, for more consider using a loop):

```
if (hero.getPos() == 6 || hero.getPos() == 11 | hero.getPos() == 16)) {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Right", "Left"};
} else {
    move = new Object[] {"Up", "Down", "Right", "Left"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you're going to need to  check `ci.getNumber() == ...` for each value, or add them to a collection and check `myCollection.contains(ci.getNumber())`. However, you may want to re-think the structure of your code if you are checking a method against several known values.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

using the answer from:

[How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

you could create an array of numbers and check if your ci.getNumber() is in it.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

There is no such operator. But if you are comparing number, you can use switch do simulate that. Here is how:

```
int aNumber = ci.getNumber();
swithc(aNumber) {
    case 6252001:
    case 5855797:
    case 6251999: {
        ...
        break;
    }
    default: {
        ... // Do else.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

No. You could create a `Set<Integer>` once and then use that, or just:

```
int number = ci.getNumber();
if (number == 6252001 || number == 5855797 || number == 6251999)
```

I'd also consider changing those numbers into constants so that you get more meaningful code.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean theyAretheSame = num1 == num2 ? (num1 == num3 ? true:false):false;
```

I must admit I haven't checked this but the logic looks correct.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the numbers in a collection, and then use the `contains()` method. Other than that, I don't believe there is any special syntax for comparing like you want to do.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 0):

Java won't let you do that. You can do a hash lookup (which is overkill for this) or a case statement, or a big honking ugly multiple compare:

```
if ((n==1 ) || (n==2) || ...
```

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values

Answer (score 0):

no.. you have to compare them individually.

Comment: FYI: this answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001691/java-operators-compare-multiple-values