# Is there a way to create an AND/OR/ETC. Boolean statement that is comparing with the same value without redefining the value?

Tags: java

The Question is this: Is there any way to create a AND/OR/ETC. Boolean Statement that shares the same value (EX. `(1 == 0 || 1 == -1 || 1 == 2 || 1 == 31)`) without having to specify that value(`1`) each time?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228742/or-operand-with-int-in-if-statement

Comment: Unfortunate that this was closed.  There is another way to do it that is not shown in the answers to the other question.  Hint:  Use a `switch` statement.